# Get previous year til may

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want all values from last year til 2018-05-13. I want to run the query everyday so it should know that tomorrow it should get all values from last year til 2018-05-14 without specifying the date.

I use this code to get all values for this year and would like to have something similar for retrieving values from last year:

```
YEAR(Created) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: @Cid Probably SQL Server (`GETDATE()`)

Comment: *"all values from last year til 2018-05-13"* dates from 2018-01-01 to 2018-05-13 ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SQL Server 11 and yes from 2018-01-01 to 2018-05-13 without specifying those dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` to manipulate the date based on `GETDATE()` to get to where you want. You can go one step further and do `DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()), 0)))` to get the end of the day for the date one year ago.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date 
BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
AND DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
select *
from MyTable t1
where SomeDateColumn between dateadd(year,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
    and getdate()
```

This gets all of last year, and this year to date

If you just want from today last year to today:

```
select *
from MyTable t1
where SomeDateColumn between dateadd(year,-1,GETDATE()) 
    and getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
where datecol >= dateadd(year, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and
      datecol < convert(date, getdate())
```

This gets the last complete year, for both date and date/time columns.  If you want to include today, then:

```
where datecol > dateadd(year, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and
      datecol <= convert(date, getdate())
```

Comment: He wants Beginning of last year - This date last year. Not this date last year - today